# How can I save a string as a file inside a running docker container

Tags: docker

I use below command to save the string `hello` as a file in `/tmp/a` inside the docker container. But it will save `hello` in my local host dist not the container. How can I save it inside the docker?

```
docker exec -i b76f12ba2740 echo "hello" > /tmp/a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker exec -i b76f12ba2740 /bin/bash -c 'echo "hello" > /tmp/a'
```